# jQuery Click Counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a simple cookie clicker type game (click counter) with jQuery. I want to have a button that makes the value of clicks go up by one every second. How would I go about this and are there any errors in my coding? I'm very new to all of this.

Here's my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#target').click(function() {
    $('#output').html(function(i, val) {
      return val * 1 + 1;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <button id="target" type="button">Click</button>
  <div id="output">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: To avoid having to parse the number with each update, you might want to make a variable called `count` which you manipulate and display from the JS.

Answer (score 2):

A button that automatically "clicks" the button would require that you add a `setInterval` that refreshes the number continually, and another button that changes how many clicks get added with each refresh.

Here's how I would do it. I've coded it in such a way that you could easily add other buttons which change the click rate in other ways. Notice the difference between incrementing the `count` and incrementing the `countRate`. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5bo0rrx/1/)

```js
$(function() {
  var count = 0, countRate = 0, output = $('#output');

  setInterval(function(){ output.html(count) }, 1); // update continually
  setInterval(function(){ count += countRate }, 1000); // update once-per-second

  $('#click').click(function(){ count += 1 });
  $('#autoClick').click(function(){ countRate += 1 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

<button id="click">Click</button>
<button id="autoClick">Auto Click</button>
<div id="output">0</div>
```

Comment: I've updated my algorithm several times. It's much nicer now.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the bit you're struggling with is increasing the value of each click, once per second. You'll want to use `setInterval`

[jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/erresen/LdL8b4uu/9/)

```js
var score = parseInt($('#output').html());
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    score += 1;
    $('#output').html(score);
  }, 1000);

  $('#target').click(function() {
    score += 1;
    $('#output').html(score);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <button id="target" type="button">Target</button>
  <br/>
  <div id="output">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried this, but the value doesn't incease each second? Sorry I'm a huge noob at coding in general.

Comment: Hi, it's just randomly increasing the value now? What I'm trying to do is make a button that when clicked increases the value every second. And when I click the main button, it will increase the value by one.

Comment: The issue is that it's not displaying the number within the `setInterval`. The output is only getting updated when the button is clicked.

Comment: what the code does is increase the value of `clickValue` once per second, so if you click it after 1 second it'll be worth 2 (since it starts at 1), if you click after 10 it'll be worth 10. This number is then added to output.

Comment: Is there a way to start it with a seperatre button?

Comment: added a start button

Comment: But is there a way for the output to update automaticly without having to click the target?

Comment: It adds one every second once I click start but now when I click the target, it does nothing. Btw, thank you so much for all your help :)

Comment: I think i understand what you're after now... editing now

Comment: Sorry, no. What I wanted was to combine the number of clicks and the one added every second together into one, but only start adding one evry second when I click a certain button.

Comment: go to http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/ When you click the cookie, it adds one, But when you buy something from the shop, it adds more every set amount of seconds. That was what I was aiming for.

Comment: In that case look at the answer from @4castle

Comment: Updated - hopefully what you're after

Comment: Thank you soooooo much! Thanks for taking all this time to help out a horrible noob coder that understands nothing! I'm immensly happy right now

Comment: No problem. I'd appreciate it if you could marked my answer as accepted if it helped you out :)